# Nginx still showing the non existant URL when on the 404 page (index in my case)

Tags: nginx

I'm having a slight issue with Nginx and I'd be grateful if somebody could help me figure out the reason why it's not working. 
What I'd like to do is have the website redirect to the index page when the requested URL is invalid, but when using the following code:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    error_page 404 /index.php;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.php;


    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

it's not working exactly the way I'd like it to. This code works, but the URL is still `http://example.com/nonexistantpage` when showing the index page. What I'd like is for the site to redirect to the index page, making the URL `http://example.com`

Comment: I know this is stupid, but did you try `ctrl+f5`

Comment: That's not doing much in my case, since I'm on a Mac at the moment. I'd like Nginx to redirect to `http://example.com` instead of showing the requested URL whilst still pulling the index.php contents.

Comment: ok i misunderstood, i thought you were saying that an old url is still working, so you want to redirect instead of 404 is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I tried making a file called 404.php with a header redirect to the index, but that just resulted in a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok that's easy try this

```
error_page 404 =301 /;
```

if it doesn't work then use the full path

```
error_page 404 =301 http://example.com;
```

Comment: Aha! Using the full URL worked wonders. I didn't even need to use =301 in that case :-)

Comment: actually it does make a difference, check the response code of the page, it could be serving the page but with http code 404